# Does JSON accept multi-line arrays?

Tags: javascript, json, single-page-application

I am trying to build a SPA ( Single Page Application ) as a simple website using only JSON, while I am learning JavaScript.

In the technique I use, page content with HTML tags are injected by JavaScript.

Since last JavaScript versions can store data between backticks

```
`
Multi
Line 
Data
`
```

I am asking if multi-line JSON objects can store data by the same technique or something similar, so I can implement a way to edit data, without importing each tag from a HTML file, as new JavaScript framework do.

```
`` "" ''
```

For example:

```
var spa = {
..."spa_html_id_body_tag":"< h2 > body content < h2/ > < br > Bal bla bla .............."
}
```

Comment: JSON is a string representation of a JavaScript Object (JavaScript Object Notation) thus has no such concept as "newline"

Comment: `var spa = {...}` seems to indicate a JavaScript Object which is an entirely different thing.  Please clarify with some actual code perhaps here.

Comment: Works fine in the browser: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/dfkx07eg/ Test it I guess? (and there's no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is *text*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is an extremely rigid schema. It's great, but it has a couple of shortcomings, the largest of which is the inability to store multi-line strings. This can be particularly annoying for storing things like structured text and public keys in JSON for later interaction with JavaScript code in the browser or on the server in Node.

Fortunately, there is a quick and hacky solution!

Example
Imagine that we have a list of servers and their associated public keys. To store that data as JSON, we could store it as an array of comma-separated string objects, which might look something like this:

```
{
    "servers": {
        "servername.com": {
            "publicKey": [
                "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----",
                "MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA0VmDBbzXdgubV/X8JP9B",
                "rM/CqvXBey49BoYjk0ar4OA4LZnmD0A/pn6voPPe+DQC3ZpSFfkdZc5s/ij7edve",
                "ob+reWdGOQAQnDxaGQoFyru/2tz1lNfaVOBU71QcpG4kda4XDjbS62hOqebgkQ0X",
                "71ireglZeaJABvu6EFPFBwyr2ROmM1dq4rKtinpgUf9CTMPL/8yyitka+HsVZTuI",
                "HDpFFxv6xPntfjMrIIRUPieIjRSJcF9yrTVqDIIOO9J3KplphXLXhAHRAnX3ducD",
                "sZYe5yZZEdkS9Kx4P0INkyiqs9DFGwVnIMU07IuM1E+LqLVTqm46MVxzrjaAcyVC",
                "WDTtzkERgvvaG8elbjb6iiA9aijNHM/EK0f68mjme7s0CHn9GJg4TwwvSLb8LqCs",
                "cCKT11WAanE+SuAi0WinuaeFORwAFFXh7O5sS8At4woCNVsIZpFSWWiRBoZf5UBC",
                "SfK8v9AL58foDDiCGlWKcpoQN5KBDBCTBD+RiXgoCKS9daHGpmXfAFsWmcjpVzvs",
                "l24ei4Ue1jd7kj7Dlc8qtXQGZS1BhwDaIV4SQBGYKEBgTMExcsAtI9Sd1rtMFybO",
                "wdfGmZkQ7pcLqOgEzyUOma+vwhWlvtfQXavH5NEdAS+ahsf8SDAI0TQtihLxTvO5",
                "LLrORy0wclzv7V0s+6qoRuMCAwEAAQ==",
                "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can verify that this valid JSON with [JSONLint.](http://jsonlint.com/)

Then, to retrieve our text block, we just have to join them back together on the newline characters, which we can do like this:

```
var publicKey = our_data.servers['servername.com'].publicKey.join('\n');
```

And that's it! Now you can store multiline strings in JSON. It's not the prettiest thing, but it is the simplest given the constraints of JSON.

Comment: Thanks! It seams the "best" approach to read / edit the JSON file, since I am using "static data" ( JSON arrays ) that are inside the index.js. And +1 for the JSONLint site. It will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't support backticks like JavaScript template literals do. But it shouldn't be a problem. You can still create the multi-line string using a template literal, and when you call `JSON.stringify()` it will use `\n` in the JSON for the newlines.

Comment: Thanks. I will check as soon as I can, to learn that approach.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, JSON data uses strings enclosed by double quotation marks. Depending on your use-case, using HTML tags may still be the most simple solution:

```
{
    "text": "Multi<br />Line<br />Data"
}
```

If you'd prefer using the `\n` notation to represent a new line, you could then write the text as `"Multi\nLine\nData"` and - if necessary - use the `replace` method when you import it into your JavaScript:

```
JSON.parse(json).text.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

But if you want greater flexibility than that, then you'll probably need to enter the world of HTML templating. For an option that's simpler than HTML, I'd recommend taking a look at [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/). In Markdown, your example could simply be written:

```
Multi
Line
Data
```

You can reference the Markdown file in your JSON, and use that reference to import it into your JavaScript.

Comment: Does double quotes are necessary aka recommended? In fact I use single quotes for the full array, and if I need to add some code inside quotes, I  use the double quotes.

Comment: Double quotes are necessary in a JSON file (.json). If you're actually talking about an object in a JavaScript file (.js), then single quotation marks, double quotation marks or backticks are all fine.